# How to adjust multiple label vectors on the same categorical values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames (`df1`, `df2`) with the same columns (`catVar`, `label`), resulting from different sources. I would like to join these two dataframes using the `catVar` variable and create a new `label` column based on the information in `df1$label` and `df2$label`.

Is there any existing function available within the tidyverse environment?

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(catVar = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"),
                  label = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4))

df2 <- data.frame(catVar = c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
                  label = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4))

df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = c("catVar"), suffix = c("_df1", "_df2"))
# 
#    catVar label_df1 label_df2
# 1       A         1         1
# 2       B         1        NA
# 3       D         2         3
# 4       E         2         3
# 5       F         3         2
# 6       G         3         2
# 7       H         4         5
# 8       I         4         5
# 9       C        NA         1
# 10      J        NA         4
```

Expected output: the values in `catVar` tend to have similar labels but different values. For example, D, E tend to have the same value, but they have `2` in `df1$label` and `3` in `df2$label`. The label value itself is not important as long as all the common elements have the same label i.e., it does not matter `D`, `E` have `2` or `3` as long as both have the same label in the output.

Sometimes, they are present only in one data frame (J only in `df2`).

```
#    catVar label_df1 label_df2 label
# 1       A         1         1     1
# 2       B         1        NA     1
# 3       D         2         3     2
# 4       E         2         3     2
# 5       F         3         2     3
# 6       G         3         2     3
# 7       H         4         5     4
# 8       I         4         5     4
# 9       C        NA         1     1
# 10      J        NA         4     5
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how the label column is constructed. Where does the 5 come from in the label for J in your expected output?

Comment: @RichardBerry This is just a rough example; sorry for not being very clear. As I wanted to make one of the two (`df1$label`, `df2$label`) as basis to the new `label` column, I used `df1$label` and then populate the missing labels from `df2$label`. In case of `J` as the label `4` has already been assigned to `H`, `I` which had `5`. I used this unused `5` to assign for `J`. The label value itself is not important as long as all the common elements have the same label i.e., it does not matter `D`, `E` have `2` or `3` as long as both have the same label. I agree `J=5`  is still unclear.